# Angular date-picker undefined

Tags: angular

I have a date picker component in my angular and I'm trying to access its values using local reference.

However the local reference is giving me undefined when I try to console them.

Provided datepicker, the function and trigger in order below

Using angular 7:

```
<app-date-picker #startingDate class="col-12 ">
              </app-date-picker>
```

```
datesCompare(sDate, eDate){
    console.log(sDate, eDate, '-------dates------')
  }

<input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Code" 
 (click)="datesCompare(startingDate, endingDate)">
```

Comment: Where are `startingDate` and `endingDate` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can get HTML element like that:

```
<app-date-picker #startingDate class="col-12 ">
</app-date-picker>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('startingDate') startingDate; 

datesCompare(){
    console.log('startingDate:', this.startingDate )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is implying that you need the template reference of your custom date-picker component. If that is indeed the case then you should try doing

```
@ViewChild('startingDate') startingDate;
@ViewChild('endingDate') endingDate;
```

Then in `ngAfterViewInit` block, you can console.log your `startingDate` and `endingDate` variables to confirm they are not undefined.
So that now when you run your `datesCompare` function it does not return undefined for both the dates.

But if you are looking for doing any computation on the dates selected by each of the date pickers then you should resort to using **@Output** decorator
i.e. in your **AppDatePicker** component, you can have a variable called *selectedDate* that represents the selected date and an emitter **dateSelection** as:

```
selectedDate: Date;  
@Output()dateSelection = new EventEmitter<Date>{};
```

Then in your **AppDatePicker** component, when the date is selected you can call

```
this.dateSelection.emit(this.selected);
```

In Parent component HTML:

```
<app-date-picker #startingDate (dateSelection)="getStartingDate($event)" class="col-12 "></app-date-picker>
```

In Parent component TS :

```
getDate(event){
    this.startingDate = event //The event here is basically the date value 
                                that you have emitted from your component
}
```

The same you can do for endingDate as well